# Android:use debugmode in galaxy s2

Tags: android, debugging

I am using new device for testing named Samsung Galaxy SII but i am unable to use use debugging mode that means i am unable to see logs in my emulator but i am able to connect it with usb mode but not with debugging mode.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You need to download the samsung kies drivers.  You can download it from samsung's website.

Comment: i have visited samsung site and i found nothing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download Samsung Kies and inastall it in your pc and then restart your device and pc too..It will surely work..

Answer (score 7):

Do the following :

1). Download & install samsung Kies driver on your PC.

2). Turn on USB debugging :
  Settings -> Applications ->Development -> USB debugging

3). Connect your samsung galaxy with the PC.

5). Run the app mannually (Select the galaxy tab at runtime).

6). Finally on DDMS select the galaxy tab device.

Check the logcat now.

Comment: my problem is thid that i am unable to download samsung Kies driver

Comment: check this link : http://www.bestfreewaredownload.com/freeware/t-free-samsung-kies-freeware-sunynzug.html  If it can help u..

Comment: still the debugging mode is not working in emulator i.e. the device is not shown in emulator

Comment: You can never see ths device on emulator. Once the device will be connected to system , you can check the logcat.

Comment: but when i run my app the emulator starts , but the device  dont installed the build

Comment: Run the app mannualy , this will ask you for the device(emulator or real device) at runntime, you want use for installing the app. try it.

Comment: app dont ask , it directly chooses emulator

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings -> Applications ->Development -> USB debugging, have you turned it to on ?

Comment: i have done this but after this only usb mass storage gets open not the debugging mode

Comment: i have done it but only usb mode is on not the debugging mode

Answer (score 1):

Have u made android:debuggable=true in the manifest file?
If this is not true, the device will not be available in debugging mode..

Answer (score 1):

To debug applications on our android samsung galaxy S4, we must take steps like these, and I think it is also valid for the galaxy s2:

First we install the USB device drivers;

After the device must follow these steps:

1 - Select Apps

2 - Go to Settings

3 - Select More -> About Device

4-7 times on Tap Build Number

5 - Select More -> Developer options

6 - Check USB debugging

7 - Select OK to allow USB debugging

8 - Check USB debugging

They may find more information at the following link
http://www.systemdeveloper.info/2013/12/enablement-usb-debugging-in-samsung.html