# android:implementing google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an app in which i am using google map and my code snippet foe main xml is as follows:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
     android:id="@+id/mapview1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:apiKey="0lr6nShkIg955xnYpmUOgPpsSuEJctwQIUXExhw"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:enabled="true" >
 </com.google.android.maps.MapView>
```

and my java code is:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class MapList extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("hello1");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("hello");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

}

and android manifest is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission  
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

but on compile time it gives me exception:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.trigma.map/com.trigma.map.MapList}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trigma.map.MapList in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.trigma.map-1.apk]`.

Can anyone help me how to solve this?

Comment: are you including the google stuff in your initial Android project setup?

Comment: have you define MapList currectly in manifest with correct package level and all// Please check again

Comment: Looks like he is - `import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;`.  There's a few more though (at least on the Google Maps tutorial):  GeoPoint, MapView, Overlay and OverlayItem (all in the com.google.android.maps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you have written this but Have you defined this line

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

in between the `<application> here </application>` Tag?

Yesterday i did the same mistake,so just asking to check.

Comment: i checked it but still same exception

Comment: Thanks for your help and it worked perfectly now and +1 for help.

Comment: can you help me in this also :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046111/androiduse-debugmode-in-galaxy-s2

Comment: for above question all answers are useful and there's nothing to say more..just follow them,and right click the app and select run as -> run configuration also close your other emulators

Comment: check if phone setting->Application->developement->usb debugging is true?

Comment: i checked that. Its true only