# USB Debugging not working, tried everything

Tags: android, debugging

I know this is kind of obsolete, but I can't get it to work. I have Android 4.2.2 and Windows 8.1. When I plug it in USB debugging mode the command: adb devices there is an empty list. I tried:

- installing "ADB, Fastboot and Drivers"
- unlocking Developer Options in Android
- adb kill-server / adb start-server
- changing USB port
- restarting Windows and Android
- deleting "C:\Users\****\.android\" contents

Nothing works. Please help!
Thanks in advance,
Adi.

Comment: have you tried using a different phone cable

Comment: No, but I use the same that I use to transfer files. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Does your device support file transfer via the cable? If yes, have you switched USB modes between PTP, MTP, MIDI, charging? Have you turned on "USB debugging" in settings? What is a device? Maybe Xiaomi that has also some security settings for USB? Once I installed several USB drivers.

Comment: Yes, the cable successfully transfers files. I tried both MTP and PTP without success. I have "USB Debugging" checked in Developer Options. It is a Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: When I plug in my phone, in Device Manager appear Portable Device directory with my phone name item as well as an item with my phone model in Other Devices with a warning icon. The second mentioned item doesn't does not accept any drivers. Might this be a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should install Google USB and Web Drivers in SDK Manager:

[image]

Also maybe you should try to install Samsung Android USB Driver.

See also http://www.itjungles.com/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-how-to-enable-usb-debugging.html and [Android:use debugmode in galaxy s2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046111/androiduse-debugmode-in-galaxy-s2) (maybe install Samsung Kies).

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply and sorry for my late reply. I'll try all of these and let you know.

Comment: @Ady, glad to hear you!

Comment: Just can't get Kies to work... (The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application...). But trying.

Comment: @Ady, well, I don't know. Do you really have to support such an old device? Maybe buy another old device? Or make a factory reset? I plugged Galaxy S3, S4, S5 and didn't encouner a problem.

Comment: OK, I've managed to install Kies and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ady, very glad to hear it! Good luck!